# multiple joins with the same table in eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Is there some elegant way to write the following query in eloquent? I would like to avoid using the raw query:

```
results(id, data)
result_filters (id, result_id, filter_id, value)

SELECT * FROM results, result_filters as age, result_filters as followers
WHERE age.result_id = results.id
AND followers.result_id = results.id
AND age.filter_id = 2
AND age.value > 90
AND followers.filter_id = 6
AND followers.value < 10000
```

Comment: can you please share the relationship between this model i.e results and result_filters ?

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati result_filters references results via result_filters.resultid = results.id

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the laravel eloquent
your model relation could be like

model Result:

```
public function resultFilters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ResultFilter');
    }
```

model ResultFilter:

```
public function result()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Result','result_id');
    }
```

try the below code:

```
$result = Result::find(1);
$data = $result->resultFilter()
            ->whereIn('filter_id',[2,6])
            ->whereBetween('value',[90,10000])
            ->get();
```

Comment: I think this would be equal to (filter_id = 2 OR filter_id = 6) AND value > 90 AND value < 10000. But the values are tied to the filter_id, so I need filter_id = 6 with value < 10000 and filter_id =2 with value > 90

Comment: it will return you the collection which has the filter_id = 2 AND filter_id = 6  AND value between 90 & 10000

Comment: but I want the value for filter_id 2 to be > 90 and for filter_id 6 to be < 10000. Your query does not distinguish that. It applies the between 90 & 10000 condition to both

Answer (score 0):

What do you think? It's uses DB::raw but it works

```
$data = DB::table(DB::raw("results, result_filters as age, result_filters as followers "))
->select(DB::raw("* "))
->where('age.result_id', 'results.id')
->where('followers.result_id', 'results.id')
->where('age.filter_id', 2)
->where('age.value', '<', 90)
->where('followers.filter_id',6)
->where('followers.value','<',10000)
->get();
```